# Prove that $g:X→Y$ is a continuous and surjective map

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is  the union of the line segments $[0,1]\times \{n\}$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and let $Y$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all points of the form $(x,\frac{x}{n})$ for $x∈[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Let us define a map $g:X\to Y$ by the equation $g(x,n)=(x,\frac{x}{n})$. Then show that g is surjective and continuous .

I have realized that $X$ is the union of countably many disjoint line segments and $Y$ is the union of countably many line segments having an end point in common. So I have already done that $g$ is a surjection. But failed to solve for continuous part.
Pleas help me to clarify this.

Comment: Have you tried letting $(x_k, n_k) \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} (x, n)$ and showing that $g(x_k, n_k) \to g(x, n)$ ? This goes really effortlessly.

Comment: @Adayah. I have tried this way already. For a particular sequence $\{x_n\}$ this works like $x_n=(1/n,n_k)$, but I failed whenever it is in the case of arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x_k, n_k) \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} (x, n)$. Then $x_k \to x$ and $n_k \to n$, but since $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is discrete, we have $n_k = n$ for all $k$ except finitely many. Thus

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} g(x_k, n_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} g(x_k, n) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( x_k, \frac{x_k}{n} \right) = \left( x, \frac{x}{n} \right)$$

because $\frac{x_k}{n} \to \frac{x}{n}$ while $n$ is fixed.

Comment: Sir I can't get the line in your proof that " since $Z_+$ is discrete, we have $n_k=n$ for all $k$ except finitely many". Please elaborate this.

Comment: @abcdmath  We know that $n_k\to n$.  Use the $\varepsilon$ definition with $\varepsilon=1/2$.  Then if (to the contrary) infinitely many $n_k\neq n$, then every tail would have an $n_k$ in it, so no tail would be within $\varepsilon$ of $n$.